# why does the error"java.util.NoSuchElementException" get thrown?

Tags: java

This question is copied from Hackerrank:

> Gary is an avid hiker. He tracks his hikes meticulously, paying close attention to small details like topography. During his last hike, he took exactly  steps. For every step he took, he noted if it was an uphill or a downhill step. Gary's hikes start and end at sea level. We define the following terms:
>
> A mountain is a non-empty sequence of consecutive steps above sea level, starting with a step up from sea level and ending with a step down to sea level.
>
> A valley is a non-empty sequence of consecutive steps below sea level, starting with a step down from sea level and ending with a step up to sea level. Given Gary's sequence of up and down steps during his last hike, find and print the number of valleys he walked through.
>
> Input Format:
>
> The first line contains an integer, , denoting the number of steps in Gary's hike.
>
> The second line contains a single string of  characters. Each character is (where U indicates a step up and D indicates a step down), and the character in the string describes Gary's  step during the hike.
>
> Constraints:
>
> Output Format:
>
> Print a single integer denoting the number of valleys Gary walked through during his hike.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> 8
>   UDDDUDUU
>
> Sample Output:
>   1
>
> Explanation:
>   If we represent _ as sea level, a step up as /, and a step down as \, Gary's hike can be drawn as:
>
> ```
> _/\      _
>    \    /
>     \/\/
> ```
>
> It's clear that there is only one valley there, so we print  on a new line.

This is the solution which I submitted:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        String arr = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            arr += scan.next();
        }

        int total = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        boolean isValley = false;
        String sub = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
            sub = arr.substring(i, i + 1);
            if(sub.equals("U")){
                total++;
            }
            if(sub.equals("D")){
                total--;
            }
            if(total == 0){
                isValley = true;
            }
            if(total < -1 && isValley){
                counter++;
                isValley = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure as to why, but the ide throws this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862) at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371) at Solution.main(Solution.java:12)

Comment: can someone explain to me as to why i deserve -6 on a legitimate question   I have on my code? I'm not asking for you to solve the question for me, I solved it already, my code just isn't running correctly in their online ide for some reason.

Comment: Where is the legitimate question? I can't see it.

Comment: Why is my question not legitimate? I'm asking why would my code not work in their online ide

Comment: I'm not sure what your question even is.

Comment: Again, what could be causing my code to not run and throw this error, Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
 at Solution.main(Solution.java:12), when i run it on Hackerrank site?

Comment: We're looking for a question like "Why doesn't this bit compile?" or "The result is 7 because the loop doesn't exit when I expect, why doesn't "If x > 5 then break;" work? You could try reading [ask] or  [mcve].

Comment: How should rephrase my question?

Comment: Throw which error? You haven't stated what the error is. Are you getting an exception? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: In the comment above I stated what error.

Comment: If it "Runs perfectly in my IDE", then why does it have an error?

Comment: I don't know, that's why i'm asking, because I can't the reason as to why it throws the error.

Comment: I would just edit the code to add a check to see if there is a next element for you to grab before trying to grab it. I think this would be easier than trying to guess why the website's tool is throwing an error.

Comment: @DanielM Presumably because the tool doesn't enter data the same way a user at an IDE console does.

Comment: I'm rather suspicious about `isValley = false;`. I would expect that it should be `isValley = counter < 0;`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, why would isValley = false be a problem?

Comment: I've made significant improvements to the formatting and title here, which may have helped avoid downvotes. The big issue is understanding what is your content and what is copied from an external source, and it probably still needs more pre-formatting for the examples. The title was too chatty and non-specific. Hope this feedback helps.

Comment: `During his last hike, he took exactly steps` - should this have a number in it?

Comment: `The first line contains an integer, , denoting the number of steps in Gary's hike` is missing an algebraic variable?

Comment: ^ OP, if you can fix these problems, I'll consider voting to reopen. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer, did I make satisfactory edits to the question?

Comment: No, the two phrases I drew attention to remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner#next` reads a whole token, not a character. Inside your `for` loop

```
arr += scan.next();
```

consumes the `UDDDUDUU` on the first pass. There is nothing left to read on the second pass. Thus, `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Then how would you add single string characters and not the whole token?

Comment: @ZivBrodie Just take in the whole string at once and split it up. It looks like your code is taking the whole string anyways.

Comment: As @DanielM. said, there is no point in breaking the string into characters just to concatenate the back together.

Comment: Use String step_info = in.next();